# smoothly transition removeClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I've looked at other questions and it seems no one is having the same problem as me, which is always exciting!

I am trying to have a neat look on my pages content when you arrive to the page. Everything all blocked out with CSS. A big link to click that removes all the redaction effects. I have successfully managed to make the jQuery remove the redacted style classes but it isn't animating at all. I am using the jQuery UI library. I saw someone mention that it wouldn't work with `!important` attribute, I have no difference with or without, without `!important` i am not able to override the properties.

Please help obiwan, you are my only hope!

** Note, I am trying to use a JQuery UI ability not straight Jquery**

example of effect : http://api.jqueryui.com/removeClass/

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/n7wky/)

[Live dev site](http://dev.ahopefilm.com/)

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#educate").addClass("redactedtext redactedblocks" );
    $("#join").click(function() {
      $("#educate").removeClass("redactedtext redactedblocks", 1000 );
      $('#join').contents().unwrap();
    });
});
```

and the PHP/Body text

```
<article class="row">
  <article class="twelve columns mastblock predacted " id="make">
    <p><a href="#" id="join">Join</a> us in making a <strong>new</strong> kind of documentary</p>
  </article>
</article>

<section class="row " data-match-height >
  <article class="radius-top-left medium-4 columns mastblock " id="educate">
    <h1>Educational</h1>

    <p>Find out what is behind the actions that lead to slavery, human trafficking, and forced Labour. Have a more complete picture on why slavery still exsists.</p>

    <p>Learn more&#8230;</p>
  </article>
```

intended action is to click button, see blackout fade away and colour come back.

Comment: perhaps a jsfiddle might help us to help you...

Comment: You can't do this. Which is probably why *no one is having the same problem as you*. You can transition individual css properties but not an entire class.

Comment: so if I use jquery to removeClass i can't made it fade it out? I'd have to transition the background and text colours specifically? can I use a class as an end point (so that I can just call once and have it change to the correct colours for each box) ?

Comment: According to this document http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/ There's no **duration** option for `.removeClass()`. You can place a black div above that text then hide it with `.fadeOut()`

Comment: **You can transition individual css properties but not an entire class**? care to actually explain what you mean? do you mean removing a class?

Comment: I understand that jQuery does not allow for a duration to a removeClass, however jQuery UI is supposed to allow for it.http://jqueryui.com/removeClass/

Comment: Think about it. Animation is a series of sub-states between two states. But can you partially apply a class? What does it mean 50% of `float: left`? Or 20% of `background-image: url(sprite.png)`?

Comment: My last comment was for @Liam

Comment: is it possible though to make these classes animate away with the jquery UI? The example seems to show that you can, but for some reason I can't get my site to do that. Do one of you see what i'm doing incorrectly?

example here : http://api.jqueryui.com/removeClass/

Comment: You can use CSS3 or jQuery's .animate() to get fading..

Comment: @Pinocchio, there is not way (in native Jquery) to *"Go from this class to this class gradually"*. You can use `animate` to alter individual CSS properties, color, etc. but not an entire class, like the OP is trying to do.

Comment: @Liam yeah i know but believe it or not you can in jQuery UI, and that is what OP is using

Comment: Well answer the question then @Pinocchio?

Comment: @Liam i don't know the answer. because OP is using what i just told you and it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS Animation provides a much more versatile solution for this problem. Works in all  major browsers( with some caveats...)

here's and example, based on what I think you are trying to achieve...

http://jsfiddle.net/adrianjmartin/xLpft/

```
<style>
.redacted {
  background-color:black;
  color:black;
 }

 @keyframes unredact{
  to{
   background-color:white;
   }
  }
 @-webkit-keyframes unredact{
    to{
    background-color:white;
 }
}

</style>

<script>
  window.addEventListener( "load" , function(){

  var p = document.querySelectorAll("P");



  for( var ii = 0 ; ii < p.length ; ii++ ){

    var t = p[ii].textContent;
    var a = t.split( ' ' );
    var h = "";

    for( var i = 0 ; i < a.length ; i++ ){
      h += "<span class='redacted'>"+a[i]+" </span>";
    }
    p[ii].innerHTML = h ;
    }

  });

  window.addEventListener( "click" , function(){

    var spans = document.querySelectorAll( "P span.redacted");
    for( var i = 0; i < spans.length ; i++ ){
    var delay = Math.random(3);

       var delay = Math.random(3);
    var style = "-webkit-animation: unredact forwards 3s " + delay + "s;";
        style += "animation: unredact forwards 3s " + delay + "s";
    }
  });
</script>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce quis fringilla nisi. Curabitur vitae mi ultrices nunc sodales sodales at eget est. Aenean placerat eleifend lorem sed congue. Vivamus rutrum mi tempus leo interdum, vel volutpat velit consequat. Pellentesque eu sem metus. Nullam quis mauris ultrices augue blandit consequat. Vestibulum sollicitudin odio sed lobortis lacinia. Vivamus semper est et sapien ultrices, non vestibulum sapien tincidunt. Vivamus nunc neque, tincidunt ut arcu quis, bibendum hendrerit odio. Suspendisse id molestie ligula. Nulla dapibus venenatis tellus, egestas imperdiet velit pretium pellentesque. Mauris risus nibh, feugiat et magna sit amet, malesuada sagittis tellus. Curabitur porta, turpis ac tincidunt pharetra, augue est sodales ipsum, vitae pharetra eros nisl nec ante. Duis mattis volutpat est, in hendrerit urna mattis sed.<p>

<p>In bibendum nisl sit amet libero tempus ullamcorper. Vivamus a augue scelerisque, fermentum lorem et, vehicula justo. Praesent aliquet venenatis libero eget bibendum. Nam imperdiet fermentum libero et sagittis. Fusce varius posuere arcu, convallis varius ante aliquam ac. Proin eu nisi commodo, interdum erat vitae, iaculis massa. Fusce quis elit ac lacus viverra adipiscing. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed sodales mauris non condimentum ultricies. Maecenas at venenatis arcu. Vestibulum scelerisque lacinia libero, eu tincidunt diam egestas eu. Suspendisse eu eros nulla. Ut dignissim nisl sed turpis tristique aliquam.
</p>
```

Comment: awesome this is great, however is there a way to make this work for each class to the specific background colours that the class has? I guess I could build one of these for each class, but i'd prefer to type less code :P

Comment: The animation is defined in an at-block in the CSS call 'keyframes', it can have a 'from' defined too, or can use 0%{...} 50%{...} 100%{...} instead, plus loads of other settings, see http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/

http://www.sitepoint.com/build-awesome-apps-with-css3-animations/

http://caniuse.com/#search=animation

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673530(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I've updated the code above and the fiddle, beware JSFiddle css formatting script is not total ok with the at-block syntax!

Comment: this fiddle shows one way to animation 'back' to the css defined colours  http://jsfiddle.net/adrianjmartin/fcYne/

Comment: Hey Adrian, is there any way to simplify the code for triggering the animation? I need to break this up a bit as it does the right affect however I am not fully understanding how the animation is being called. What if I want to simply call the animation on #education text elements lets say?

Comment: Bit late...i've been away. Just update the selector used in querySelectorAll to something like "P#education span.redacted", JSFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/adrianjmartin/Nd2F7/1/

Comment: ah shucks, your code is just beyond my scope of current understanding. I would need it to be a more generic (or more controlled) bit of formatting. I would need to select specific classes, Headers, paragraph, and links.. This is the closest answer and I have used a bit of the content from this however. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is true that you cannot animate a class if it has `!important` properties as I have just tested. Here are 2 fiddles that will demonstrate that.

**!important Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/eaPcv/**

**Normal Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/eaPcv/1/**

So you are out of luck.

But saying that you have to use `!important` to otherwise the styles won't work is really not true. it is certainly possible to build a website without ever using `!important` and seeing as you have lot's of `!important` then you are writing bad code and you're doing something wrong somewhere.

Comment: this doesn't appear to work, and i understand that under jquery you can not transition a removeClass, however Jquery UI has the ability to define a duration, however it does not appear to work.

Comment: thanks, I guess I gotta figure out how to write it without the "!important" tags to override the actual styles.

Comment: Create a new class at the bottom of the stylesheet, that will over-ride another class.

Comment: that could work, I'm currently using a second CSS sheet that is called  after the main sheet. Is my understanding that wrong about CSS? I was under the assumption that it would over ride through that. PS thanks for popping my Stackoverflow cherry, I was afraid to ask because I didn't know how long it would take to answer!

Comment: for others with this issue : http://htmldog.com/guides/css/intermediate/specificity/ helped me see why my SASS files were cuaseing problems.